# motion detection and object extraction in c#?

Tags: c#, video, video-capture, video-processing

can any one help me in detect moving objects in images and extract them out using c# ? i tried to extract them by subtracting image from previous image but this did't work with me

Answer (score 2):

OpenCV is a good library to get started with this sort of thing. Be warned that it's not very well written, but the algorithms are there.

Answer (score 0):

Motion detection is a very complex subject, and isn't related to C# that much. What exactly would you like to do? What are the "objects" in the video?

Do you want to detect any motion of anything, or motion of specific objects?

Can your application recognize the objects and differentiate them from the background?

Alex.

Comment: iam having say 10 images with a person that is moving and in each image he appear in different position so i want to detect this part of images(person) and extract it out from images then i can overlapp all images and at the end i can get one single image with no person in it :)

Comment: can you understand my idea now ??

Comment: Comparing the pixel difference between the frames is probably the approach that you want then.